# Using the same argument names for a function defined inside another function

Tags: r, function, arguments

Why does

```
f <- function(a) {
    g <- function(a=a) {
        return(a + 2)
    }
    return(g())
}
f(3)  # Error in a + 2: 'a' is missing
```

cause an error?  It has something to do with the a=a argument, particularly with the fact that the variable names are the same.  What exactly is going on?

Here are some similar pieces of code that work as expected:

```
f <- function(a) {
    g <- function(a) {
        return(a + 2)
    }
    return(g(a))
}
f(3)  # 5

f <- function(a) {
    g <- function(g_a=a) {
        return(g_a + 2)
    }
    return(g())
}
f(3)  # 5

g <- function(a) a + 2
f <- function(a) g(a)
f(3)  # 5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that, [as explained in the R language definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-matching):

> The default arguments to a function are evaluated in the evaluation frame of the function.

In your first code block, when you call `g()` without any arguments, it falls back on its default value of `a`, which is `a`. Evaluating that in the "frame of the function" (i.e. the environment created by the call to `g()`), it finds an argument whose name matches the symbol `a`, and its value is `a`. When it looks for the value of that `a`, it finds an argument whose name matches that symbol, and whose value is `a`. When...

As you can see, you're stuck in a loop, which is what the error message is trying to tell you:

```
Error in g() : 
  promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or 
earlier problems?
```

---

Your second attempt, which calls `g(a)` works as you expected, because you've *supplied* an argument, and, [as explained in the same section of R-lang](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-matching):

> The supplied arguments to a function are evaluated in the evaluation frame of the calling function.

There it finds a symbol `a`, which is bound to whatever value you passed in to the outer function's formal argument `a`, and all is well.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the `a=a` part.  An argument can't be its own default. That is a circular reference.

This example may help clarify how it works:

```
x <- 1
f <- function(a = x) { x <- 2; a }
f()
## [1] 2
```

Note that `a` does not have the default 1; it has the default 2. It looks first in the function itself for the default.  In a similar way `a=a` would cause `a` to be its own default which is circular.

Comment: and the error message in R 3.1.1 is `Error in g() : 
  promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems? `

Comment: That's much more helpful than the error message I saw (Error: 'a' is missing).  I have R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing"